# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am facing this issue while trying to implement a delete functionality using react-redux.

[image: enter link description here]

**action/profile.js**

```js
export const deleteExperience = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/profile/experience/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Experience Removed", "success"));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

**reducers/profile.js**

```
case UPDATE_PROFILE:
  return {
    ...state,
    profile: payload,
    loading: false
  };
case PROFILE_ERROR:
  return {
    ...state,
    error: payload,
    loading: false
  };
```

Comment: But at which line do you get `Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined` if it's inside catch - try to console.log first `err.response` and see what properties exist

Comment: @Zydnar I tried to console.log err.response but I am not getting anything. Actually, the deletion is working fine entries are being deleted from DB. But instead of showing success alert the catch block code running

Comment: If deletion works this means try block runned, but it deosn't mean the error is somwere else `Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined` it means `err.response` is undefined - maybe you're catching wrong type of error. Wrap content of your catch block in `if(err.response){` and else console.error(err)

Comment: Can you try by temporarily removing this line   `dispatch(setAlert('Experience Removed', 'success'))` ?  If it works can you add setAlert code to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the deletion API. API should work like this http://localhost:5000/api/profile/experience/5df8f54012b7a81ac04d6b25 but somehow it is working in this way also http://localhost:5000/api/profile/experience/5d with user's token. So I have changed api code from

```
try {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
    const removeIndex = profile.education.map(item => item.id).indexOf(req.params.edu_id)
    profile.education.splice(removeIndex, 1)

    await profile.save()
    res.json({ msg: 'Education Deleted'})
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    res.status(500).send('Server Error')
}
```

to

```
try {
    const foundProfile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
    const eduIds = foundProfile.education.map(edu => edu._id.toString());
    const removeIndex = eduIds.indexOf(req.params.edu_id);
    if (removeIndex === -1) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server error" });
    } else { 
        foundProfile.education.splice(removeIndex,1);
        await foundProfile.save();
        res.json({ msg: 'Education Deleted'})
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server error" });
}
```

Now it is working fine.